# How to use font awesome icons in jasper report?

Tags: jasper-reports

I want to use font awesome icons in my report like user icon with person name I have tried it by using Unicode even I am able to print some icons using Unicode but not all icons.

Is it possible to load font awesome icons in a report?

Answer (score 0):

To use the font you need first to download it and include it as a [custom font-extension](https://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/custom-font-font-extension).

This is how I defined them

[image: Font definition]

`fa-regular-400.ttf` in Regular and `fa-solid-900.ttf` in Bold

Now you can start to use them in your report in text fields, using [unicode characters expressions](https://community.jaspersoft.com/documentation/tibco-jaspersoft-studio-user-guide/v630/using-unicode-characters-expressions), note it will **not** work in **static text** fields (since it's not evaluated). To know the correct unicode checkout the [FontAwesome site](https://fontawesome.com/icons?d=gallery&s=regular,solid&m=free), it will show the unicode once you click on a icon.

## A simple example with some charts

**jrxml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="FontAwsome" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="570800da-28d0-4e48-a0f5-806208bd875e">
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <title>
        <band height="65" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="10" y="10" width="300" height="40" uuid="641fe55c-008a-4d90-a7c8-076a03488299"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="FontAwesome" size="20" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["\uf080 \uf1fe \uf200"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </title>
</jasperReport>
```

You need to set the `fontName` same as you defined in font-extensions and attention (in free version) all symbols are not present both in regular and solid (bold). In my case in fact I had to set the textfield to bold since the symbols are only present in `fa-solid-900.ttf`

**Output**

[image: result]